# How do I correctly upgrade the kernel on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, kernel

I'm trying to upgrade the linux kernel from 2.6.32-34 to the latest update of that series, which appears to be 2.6.32-34.

I ran:

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
```

At this point i was told that some packages were kept back:

```
   The following packages have been kept back:
     landscape-common linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
```

I proceeded to install those and then to autoremove the kernel (that's what apt-get recommended):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

My problem is that after booting, and running uname -a i still get the 2.6.32.34 kernel.

How can I guarantee that the latest kernel will be loaded?

thank you in advance.

Comment: One thing I did was to remove the linux-image for the 2.6.32-34 version. After that, the server booted but failed to load, among other things, iptables because it could'nt find load  the file /lib/modules/2.6.32-34-server/modules.dep, I would have thought that with no kernel 2.6.32-34 installed and after booting, it would not be searching for modules in the 32-34 directory. To me it looks like this whole issue is a missing symlink or something like that. But I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is dist-upgrade as already stated:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It sounds like you've already installed it manually however, so your system probably didn't have the grub updated automatically - it's one of triggers that get done if you do it correctly with apt-get.  You can update grub at any time though with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

There's no need to remove previous kernels, and in fact you should leave some known working ones there in case the current one breaks - it gives you more options for recovering the system than you would have otherwise.  They will appear in the grub menu, though the latest should appear first on the list and the one that is booted automatically after the 10 second timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the official backported 2.6.35 and 2.6.38, you'll find them in Synaptic (search for 'linux'). I found that they caused some problems with my system though, YMMV.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for the latest patch release(?) of 2.6.32, since the current kernel that I have seems to have a bug that in certain conditions causes a kernel panic after 220 days of uptime (or something like that).

Comment: What happens when you select the linux-generic, and linux-image-generic in Synaptic and select "upgrade"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the console, I don't have access to Synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

To know if you have the latest image, you can search for other package availability :

```
apt-cache search linux-image
```

That will list you all available package for kernel image.
Then you can use `apt-get install` to install the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

i personaly do it like that i go to ubuntu kernel ppa and try latest stable version of kernel for linux ( now its 3.6.2) .There are .deb packages to download: all.deb , headers,deb and image.deb (depending on ur pc its 64 bit or 32) install them with gdebi manager or with dpkg -i /path to package/.deb but be sure to remove proprietary grafic driver first or you will get black screen on login.